# JTextArea Not Showing When repaint(), but Graphics not updating when revalidate()?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextarea, repaint

I am making a program that simulates an NHL Draft Lottery, where there should be a JTextField on the right of the screen, and draftballs being drawn on the left that bounce around. I made a class called Ball that implements Runnable, and runs as a Thread in my main DraftLottery class. However, when my draw method calls repaint(), the JTextArea doesn't show. I tried switching repaint() to revalidate(), but then balls weren't moving. Then I tried calling repaint() and revalidate(), but it acted the same as repaint().
Here is the code for my DraftLottery class:

```
package ca.WiltzSports.DraftLottery;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import ca.WiltzSports.DraftLottery.DraftBall.Ball;

public class DraftLottery extends JFrame {
public static final long serialVersionUID = 89L;

int teams;
String[] teamNames;
int[] balls;
JTextArea display;
JPanel screen;
JPanel animation;
List<String> entries;
public static List<Ball> ball;
String [] draftOrder;
Random rand;
int counter = 1;
javax.swing.Timer t;
public static int width = 1024;
public static int height = 768;
Graphics dbg;
Image dbImage;
int i = 0;

public DraftLottery(int teams, String[] teamNames, int[] balls){
    t = new javax.swing.Timer(2000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            draft();
        }   

    });
    ball = new ArrayList<Ball>();
    rand = new Random();
    this.teams = teams;
    this.teamNames = teamNames;
    this.balls = balls;
    this.screen = new JPanel();
    this.animation = new JPanel();
    display = new JTextArea(20,50);
    display.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    display.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    draftOrder = new String[teams];
    this.entries = new ArrayList<String>();
    addTeamBalls();
    setSize(width,height);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Draft Lottery");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    screen.add(display);
    add("East", new JScrollPane(display));
    add("West", animation);
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) dbg;
    draw(g2d);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    Ball.runBalls(ball);
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
    for (Ball b: ball){
        b.draw(g2d);
    }
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

public void addTeamBalls(){
    for (int c = 0; c < teamNames.length; c++){
        for (int j = 0; j < balls[c]; j++){
            entries.add(teamNames[c]);
            ball.add(new Ball(rand.nextInt(width/2 - Ball.SIZE), rand.nextInt(height - Ball.SIZE), teamNames[c], i++));
        }
    }
}

public void draft(){
    int q = 0;
    String [] e = entries.toArray(new String[entries.size()]);
    String draftedTeam;
    int index = rand.nextInt(entries.size());
    draftedTeam = e[index];
    if(!draftedTeam.equals("X")){
        display.append("" + counter++ + ". " + draftedTeam + "\n");
        for(int c = 0; c < e.length; c++){
            if (e[c].equals(draftedTeam)){
                e[c] = "X";
            }
        }
        removeBalls();
    }else {
        boolean again = false;
        for (int c = 0; c < e.length; c++){
            if (!e[c].equals("X")){
                again = true;
            }
        }
        if(again){
        }else{
            t.stop();
            display.append("DRAFT LOTTERY COMPLETE");
        }
    }
    entries = Arrays.asList(e);
}

public void removeBalls(){
    Ball [] bs;
    int q = 0;
    for (Ball b: ball){
        if (b.getTeamName().equals("X")){
            continue;
        }else{
            q++;
        }
    }
    bs = new Ball[q];
    q = 0;
    for (Ball b: ball){
        if (!b.getTeamName().equals("X")){
            bs[q++] = b;
        }
    }
    ball = Arrays.asList(bs);
}
```

}

Any help would be greaty appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `revalidate();
    repaint();` should probably be at the end of your `draft()` method. At least, they should definitely not be called from `paintComponent` (through your `draw()` method): this will create an infinite painting loop

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of problems:

1. You've overridden the `paint` method of a top level container.  This is generally not recommend, as it's not double buffered and can produce flicker with animation and other paint updates.
2. You've failed to call `super.paint`. The `paint` mathod is responsible for pulling all the sub-paint methods together, including, `paintComponents`; but since you're not allowing `paint` to do it's job, it's not rendering those components for you.

Instead,

1. Create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel`.
2. Add all the required logic for the animation to this component.
3. Override it's paintComponent method and add all your animation and custom painting to it.
4. Add it to the frame.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for this advice, it's this kind of advice that keeps these question sites going and I really appreciate it!